# Take entire page screenshot with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take a full-page screenshot using selenium and chromedriver, but I am getting this half screenshot. I have tried other methods but so far only this one works and it takes only the half-page screenshot.

Anyone can fix this using another trick, also do attach the output result.

[image: Page Screenshot]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

URL = "http://stevens.ekkel.ai"

driver.get(URL)

S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('web_screenshot.png')

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 9):

I am using a PyPI package: `Selenium-Screenshot`
You can install it by using the command - `pip install Selenium-Screenshot`
Details of this package can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/Selenium-Screenshot/

Sharing a sample patch on how to use this package for full page screenshot:

```
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping
        
#Saving screenshot
ob=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
img=ob.full_Screenshot(driver,save_path=r'D:/OneDrive -Libin/Python/Sel_python/Pytest/Screenshots',image_name="Screenshot1.png")
    
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Check the screenshot for your reference:

[image: img1]

Comment: Het thank you for the help , its work but there is a problem with the screenshot it is showing me the header also again and again. Can you fix this issue?
Here is the screenshot link [Picture Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/AsRhnwK)

Comment: Hey @Khasif, will this screenshot work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwQN9.jpg

Comment: @LibinThomas yes how did you get that one? code?

Comment: @Khasif I reomved the navigation element from the page completely. Since its a sticky navigation I found  this alternative. Sharing the patch of code below as another answer. If you think it does the job you can mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the whole page, without iterations, keys or page downs or the lambda function using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201707/how-to-take-screenshot-of-youtube-page-without-opening-the-browser-in-python-or) and only changing the screen size dimensions.

Trouble is, for your webpage at least, the width has to be re-adjusted (expanded) to take the picture of the entire header, and even then it doesn't take the full width and ends up looking stitched together.

The header width is problem in simple selenium-only code.
(on my system):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=3200x20800") # ANYTHING MORE THAN 3200 width my pycharm cant cope (Rendering error)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe") # webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
outFileName = (r'D:\08102020 Random Work\NewFolder4PythonOut')
driver.maximize_window()

URL = "http://stevens.ekkel.ai"

driver.get(URL) #time.sleep(0.5)
#driver.maximize_window()

driver.get_screenshot_as_file(outFileName+"/"+"capture4.png")
```

Also, That `--window-size=3200x20800")` size I the most I could make it on my machine (limited ram space left) before Pycharm wouldn't run or inform me in error message of **rendering** problems. But even if I could run entire page maximum, the screen shot would look like this , so I recommend you use @[Libin Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304747/libin-thomas) pytest code.

My chrome (deliberately downgraded to chrome 89 as webdriver for chrome 90 doesn't exist yet or I could find), also in a very highly markedup authoritative SO thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381324/how-can-i-control-chromedriver-open-window-size) or elsewhere  - I've read so much but haven't found a simple generic solution for us) and I [mistake it? or take it? that], as one of the highly marked answers in SO says, **Chrome Webdriver doesn't have a "take whole webpage screenshot" function yet**, as you can see in the picture, but FireFox does (which I don't want to use, cant and have deleted. RAM)

[image]

**EDIT 18:20 pm**

After doing all that , and a bit more, it dawned on me that I was looking at it the wrong way. ZOOM is what I needed.

I did manage to get a screen shot of the whole thing, clearly, in one go, using `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='10%'")` after driver opens the page.

(its helped me understand why even your first attempt, and my successful page down scrolling one,  our headers appeared stretched and where narrower than the rest of the body).

The true header is huge compared to the rest, but atleast the screen shot is real and not stretched, or only the middle section of it, Its the whole thing with the real as-is header.

(although probably not what you wanted).

[image: IMAGE Screenshot in saved folder]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options() #
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.headless = True

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201707/how-to-take-screenshot-of-youtube-page-without-opening-the-browser-in-python-or
#chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=4000x5800")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe") # webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
#driver.maximize_window()

outFileName = (r'D:\08102020 Random Work\NewFolder4PythonOut')


URL = "http://stevens.ekkel.ai"

driver.get(URL) #time.sleep(0.5)
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='10%'")
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(outFileName+"/"+"capture5.png")
```

I hope I've helped in some small way, even if not the way you maybe wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Kasif,

Im not the best, but I seem to be able to get it done, in one screenshot, no header problems, no repeating header, all headless browsing, and without any extra module imports.

I've approached it with pagedowns/ scrolling to get the full screenshot.

May need cleaning up the code a little bit, but its working as you want.

try:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

URL = "http://stevens.ekkel.ai"

driver.get(URL)

S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

# make page downs =>10 to catch the whole page

no_of_pagedowns = 15

while no_of_pagedowns:

    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)

    driver.set_window_size(S('Width'), S('Height'))  # May need manual adjustment
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('web_screenshot4.png')
    no_of_pagedowns -= 1

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question or are there bugs drawbacks, innificiencies and/or limitations in it that I can't seem to spot right now? Id like to ofcourse improve the code so # of pagedowns isn't hardcoded, but I feel would work for most sites if not all when neccissary (like infinite scrolling ).  If it's been of any help could you consider a mark up or accept my answer ? Much appreciated. Perhaps improve so one doesn't have to scroll , but I think that would be hard (though there must be a way! Settings of driver perhaps !??)

Comment: I do think it's webdriver "settings". A "page down " isn't a page down as we would think . It's fractional to that . If we could adjust those norms (I'm sure we can ), we might not even need any scrolling and your original as it is would work !   As it goes , I think this is a quick way to handle it.

Comment: Can you help with this one question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164927/selenium-getting-button-and-form-screenshot-using-chromedriver

Comment: @Khasif, Ill try!!, ill give it a go, but im out now . I will look at it & try when im back home. (p.s. it looks huge!)

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. yeah it huge because i don't know where the problem is at :)  but hope so you can just run the code and check it out easily.the outputs

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the below patch will remove the navigation ribbon and will take full page screenshot. Also I have made few edits to save the .png file as the urlname.

```
import pytest
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping
from selenium import webdriver
import time
    
###add class and mothods accordingly
page_url="http://stevens.ekkel.ai/"
driver.get(page_url)
time.sleep(5)

js_string = "var element = document.getElementsByClassName(\'w3-row w3-padding w3-black\');element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);"
driver.execute_script(js_string)
time.sleep(2)

# Saving screenshot
correction=page_url.replace("/","")
ss_name=correction.replace(":","")

ob=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
img_url=ob.full_Screenshot(
driver,save_path=r'D:/OneDrive - Libin/Python/Sel_python/Pytest/Screenshots',image_name="{}.png".format(ss_name))
```